# imwrite matlab "You may not have write permission."

Tags: matlab

I have this with imwrite in matlab it says: "You may not have write permission." I tried to change the format of the image but It doesn't work.

Comment: Where are you trying to write the image to?

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if that file already exists and is open somewhere outside MATLAB. It will fail if it is.